# Latest google play services Ads Library conflicting Issues 17.1.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, admob, google-play-services

When I update **Gradle google play services Ads Dependency** to the latest version **17.1.2**

```
      **implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2**'
```

Conflicting issues found saying:  All gms/firebase libraries must use the same version. Examples include implementation **'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2** and **implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-measurement-base:16.0.5**.

**Note**: I have not even used firebase anywhere in the app and I update the ads dependency from **version 15.0.1**.

Comment: please show project root `build.gradle` file as well as app `build.gradle` file

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Yeah, the problem solved after updating Android Studio from 3.0 to 3.2.1. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Use**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.1'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: but what if I really want to use ads version 17.1.2 the latest one?

Comment: Similar versions need to be used. check if both are available with same versions.
But if Your problem solves by using lower version then go for it.
Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

you have to choice first update all google dependency with same version or second one is remain dependency with old version.